# How to align overflow text at div box center?

Tags: html, css

Here is my question:

My headline word is overflowing the div box. The reason is that the word size is wider than div's width, and I set the "nowrap" rule. It showed like this:

[image]

I want the words “FORMAT CAMERA” to align at the center axis of the div box, so it makes part of F overflow to left, part of A overflow to right. How can I do that? Here is my simple CSS code:

```
.content {
  text-align: center;
}

h1(FORMAT CAMERA) {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's difficult to reproduce this without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 11):

Just add `display:flex` and `justify-content: center` to the `.content`.
See more about amazing [flex box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit hacky, but it works. It is achieved by adding margin left and margin-right 100% to the h1 tag. This is basically "pulling" the element in a equal amount on either side relative to the size of the window, forcing it to spill out of the content div.

I have added a `.outerspace` wrapper with `overflow:hidden` to prevent a horizontal scroll from appearing.

```css
.outerspace {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: -100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerspace">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <h1>FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```